# local domain misunderstood as search term

Tags: search, dns, local

I have a local web server for customers to order merchandises in my shop using their smart phone. The machine serving the local web also functions as a router and I have its local domain set as "start.order". When the customers type in http://start.order then it works fine.  But without the http:// part the browser will go to the default search engine, be it Google or Bing, trying to do a search on "start order."

If the browser is Google Chrome then by adding a trailing "/" it also works fine, say start.order/.  But on some unbranded browsers that come with the phones this trick won't work.

Question: Is there a universal way to tell the browser that a string is a URL rather than a search term without requiring prefixing the http:// part?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use a real, actual, registered domain name instead of something you made up yourself.